# Quicksort causing stackoverflow?

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, quicksort

This is my implementation of quicksort:

```
int choosePivotIndex(int l, int r)
{
    return l + rand() % (r + 1 - l);
}

void swap(int a[], int l, int r)
{
    int tmp = a[l];
    a[l] = a[r];
    a[r] = tmp;
}

int partition(int a[], int l, int r)
{
    int p = choosePivotIndex(l, r);
    swap(a, p, r);
    int d = l;
    for (int i = l ; i < r ; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[r])
        {
            swap(a, i, d);
            ++d;
        }
    }
    swap(a, d, r);
    return d;
}

void quickSort(int a[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r)
    {
        int p = partition(a, l, r);
        quickSort(a, l, p - 1);
        quickSort(a, p + 1, r);
    }
}

void quickSort(int a[], int len)
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr)));

    quickSort(a, 0, len - 1);
}
```

I use it like so:

```
int a[10];
quickSort(a, 10);
```

It seems to work fine for small arrays but when I provide it with a big one (e.g. `300 000` elements) I get a stack overflow error. I tried to remedy it by using recursion only on the smaller part and sorting the bigger one in a `while` loop:

```
void quickSort(int a[], int l, int r)
{
    while (l < r)
    {
        int p = partition(a, l, r);
        if (p - l < r - p)
        {
            quickSort(a, l, p - 1);
            l = p + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            quickSort(a, p + 1, r);
            r = p - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the same results. Have I done something wrong? How can I make it work for bigger arrays?

Comment: the memory for the bigger arrays is on the stack or heap?

Comment: It appears that you are passing the array by value, not by reference. I'm not sure if that is by design but with a 300,000 element array, you're going to exhaust your stack space pretty quickly.

Comment: @Baldy, you cannot pass c arrays by value, an a[] parameter is always the same as the corresponding pointer ...

Comment: @SamerTufail Stack. I tried heap now and it seems to make the application run sooooooooooooo long (it still keeps going)...

Comment: @NPS gradually reduce the size.... try the non recursive version and see at what point you can get it to work, step up from stackoverflow though.

Comment: @SamerTufail After some more testing it seems that heap vs stack doesn't affect execution times. And using heap I was able to sort `300 000` elements (more than using stack). Can't test `1 000 000` as it takes such a long time...

Comment: Does this mean that my problem isn't the sorting algorithm but the fact that I can't create a big array on stack?

Comment: @NPS I didnt think it would, I was more suggesting the stackoverflow because of the amount of elements you were putting on the stack. No room for anything else and eventually you get a stackoverflow. True, try it, remove your algorithm and try creating a huge array on the stack. See what happens :)

Comment: I did just that for `1 000 000` element array and got a stack overflow. Thanks. Make it an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Also if anyone wonders - my long execution times were caused by not initializing array elements which resulted in all of them having the same value - which I assume caused quicksort to run `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @NPS which would be its worst case, all sorted elements

Comment: @NPS would you want this summarized in an answer?

Comment: @SamerTufail the question was about the stack overflow, the cause of which is not manifest in the post code. So IMO either the question/post code is modified or no legit answer should be given ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes sure I dont mind, I just dont want it hanging around as not answered.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Yep, dumb mistake on my part

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes One could just write that the code is fine and the problem is elsewhere which would also answer my question. But I added array definition to my question so the problem is visible.

Comment: Are you enabling compiler optimizations (e.g. adding -O2 to the command line)? See the execution time here: https://ideone.com/22qf1J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the discussions in the comments section the code appears to be fine and the offending part would be the declaration of the array on the stack

```
int a[10];
```

Where this is fine for smaller arrays its easy to run into a stack overflow with large arrays, to test this you could declare a large array of `int a[1000000]` and without the quicksort code you would still get a stack overflow. It is therefore recommended to declare them on the heap by doing a `new`